# Multiple kube-shcedulers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to create a kube-shceduler that will be used by my organisation pod deployment (a data-center). The objective would be to have the pods of any deployment be split equally between the two sites of the data-center. To archive this I created a new kube-shceduler manifest (see below), in which i changed the Ports that are used and added a new configuration file (see below) using the --config parameter. The problem is that even after setting the --port parameter to a new port that isn't already used by the original kube-scheduler, it still tries to use the old one. As such the new kube scheduler can't start:

```
I1109 20:27:59.225996       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I1109 20:27:59.226097       1 registry.go:173] Registering SelectorSpread plugin
I1109 20:27:59.926994       1 serving.go:331] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
failed to create listener: failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:10251: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10251: bind: address already in use
```

How can I force the use of the specified port OR how can I delete the original kube-scheduler so that there won't be any conflict between the two. The first solution would be preferable.

Configuration kube-scheduler (manifest - /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-scheduler.yaml) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
      #- --port=0
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

Configuration kube-custom-scheduler.yaml (/etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-custom-scheduler.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-custom-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-custom-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler 
    - --config=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
    - --master=true
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=false
    - --secure-port=10269
    - --scheduler-name=kube-custom-shceduler
    - --port=10261
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10269
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
      name: customconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: customconfig 
status: {}
```

Custom configuration mentioned in the kube-custom-scheduler.yaml (/etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf):

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration

profiles:
  - pluginConfig:
      - name: PodTopologySpread
        args:
          defaultConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 1
              topologyKey: topology.kube.io/datacenter 
              whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
```

Please don't hesistate if you need more information about the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/ , the `--port` would be overwritten by the file specified by `--config`. Adding `HealthzBindAddress` and `MetricsBindAddress`  to `/etc/kubernetes/scheduler-custom.conf` works:

```
healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10261
metricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10261
```

If you want to remove the default scheduler, you can move `kube-scheduler.yaml` out of `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in the last days i tried to replace the configuration of the default kube-scheduler. after adding the option ```--config=config-file``` and mounting the mentioned config-file to the Pod of the scheduler I restarted the Master's Pods using ```systemctl restart kubelet```.

Comment: The problem is that after every restart of any change to the manifest file the kubelet run for a few second the current configuration then goes back to the original one. I tried to debug but using journalctl -u kubelet but couldn't find any error related to the kube-shceduler Pod. As such i move to another alternative to archive my goal, using Admission Controller (Kyverno) to mutate the deployments.